# What component for multilingual articles

Tags: joomla, multilingual

I have been playing with Joomla 1.6 out-of-the-box but I don't think it can achieve what I want and I therefore need your help to install the right components.

I would like to create a multilingual website with the following URL structure:

```
http://example.com/{language}/{path}
```

Example URLs:

```
http://example.com/en/hello
http://example.com/fr/bonjour
http://example.com/de/hallo
```

Right now what I see is that I need to create 1 separate article for each language and specify the language in that article.

However what I would like is for `hello`, `bonjour`, and `hallo` to be managed within 1 single article where I can create different versions of the content depending on the languages that I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked the [JoomFish](http://www.joomfish.net/) component? It does all you are asking for. The only drawback it has, in my opinion, is that it forces the editors of the content to go to Components > Joomfish > Translations to edit any translated content. Some users find it confusing.

Comment: JoomFish seems nice, the only problem is that it doesn't seem compatible with Joomla 1.6: http://www.joomfish.net/en/downloads/joomfish-core

Comment: Sorry, didn't realized the version requirement, I am still using 1.5 versions of Joomla. 1.6 has some language management included, although with a different approach than Joomfish use. Here is a related discussion about 1.6 and Joomfish: http://www.joomfish.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7557

Answer (score -1):

There are many extensions for multilingual content: [Multi-lingual Content](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content)

Comment: Indeed there are, hence my question :)